# Как установить log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

Подскажите, люди добрые, как установить log4j. Только, если можно, конкретно куда что нажать... Мучаюсь полдня, все перечитал, толком ничего не нашёл. Мне конкретно нужно, чтобы в NetBeans сделать так:

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;
```

Comment: А вы уверены что вам нужен log4j? Если вы только начинаете, то не мучайтесь и не тратьте время на него: используйте стандартный логгер: он достаточно хороший и умеет практически всё то же самое. На данном этапе вы и не заметите разницы.

Comment: Да, я начинаю только, хожу на курсы по Java, задание так, залогировать с помощью log4j.

Answer (score 2):

1. Выкидываете NetBeans.
2. Устанавливаете Intellij IDEA или Eclipse.
3. Качаете log4j library.
4. Подключаете к проекту.
5. Создаете log4j.properties в src.
6. Обращаетесь к логгеру Logger log = Logger.getLogger();

Примерно так.

Comment: Если не сложно, подскажите как в Eclipse это сделать?

Comment: всё, спасибо за ответ!!! 
всё получилось))

Comment: Не хочется поднимать холивары, но я бы не согласился. Я работал в NetBeans достаточно долго (4+ лет) и сейчас съехал на IDEA только потому, что NetBeans на грани уничтожения, и потому, что на новой работе IDEA - корпоративный стандарт.

Answer (score 1):

Выкидывать netbeans не обязательно.
В netbeans для подключения любой библиотеки, не обязательно log4j, в окне "Проекты"  в узле "Библиотеки" нажимаете "Добавить файл JAR/папку". Файл log4j.properties создаете в пакете "пакет по умолчанию" (корневая папка исходников). Затем настраиваете как [в примере](http://ithq.ru/index.php/article/view/primer-nastroyki-log4j) и все должно быть хорошо.

Comment: повторяйте за мной:  
*Я всегда буду смотреть дату публикации вопроса, прежде чем отвечать на него.*

Comment: Нда, почему то после перехода на SO в хэше всплыла туча древних вопросов